# What does allocation volume mean in the kvm storage pool?

Tags: kvm, storage

I was trying to deploy a 4GB VM with virt-install, i've symlinked the /var/lib/libvirt/images to a random directory /kvmstore as my pool and got the following :

```
virt-install --network bridge:virbr0 --name $1 --os-variant=$2 --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --disk path=/kvmstore/$1.img,size=4 --graphics none --location=$3 --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200"

The requested volume capacity will exceed the available pool space when the volume is fully allocated. (4096 M requested capacity > 3470 M available)
```

So i went in to check what was in that pool using : virsh pool-info kvmstore, and this came out

```
Capacity:       16.40 GiB
Allocation:     13.01 GiB
Available:      3.39 GiB
```

What is this Allocation Volume refering to exactly, and why does it exist, why does it take up so much space ? I can't seem to really understand the libvirt documentation on it ...

Comment: Where do you see `Allocation Volume`? `virsh pool-dumpxml kvmstore` should tell you what that pool consists of. Chances are it's some directory on some filesystem and the allocation info matches what `df` reports for that filesystem.

Comment: It seems rather that this allocation feature is a systematic mechanism that kvm storage uses for some reasons. It has to do with sparse files (since it can be worked around by enabling sparse=true and --force to get rid of the error), I won't lie i didn't have time to dig any deeper

Comment: I added in the command line "--check all=off" and he skip the "ERROR The requested volume..." But I don t found what file contain this value Cordially